# How do I make Vim preserve column position when moving between lines?

Tags: cursor-movement, spacevim

I'm using one of Vim distribution called SpaceVim and everything is good enough except some details. How do I make spacevim to preserve column position when moving between lines? For instance - move from first line and 10 column (1:10) to second line without any columns (2:1) and then get back (all using `j` and `k` keys). Now you are on 1:1 position instead of 1:10 as expected and how **nvim behaves by default**. What option or toggle is responsible for column position preserving? Thanks.

Comment: why don't you ask on the spacevim issue tracker?  as you said, preserving the column is how vim works already

Comment: @Mass I just think there is a kind of general toggle, which disable that behavior and which is enabled by default in spacevim. Also I've asked for this in spaceim glitter chat.

Comment: No, there is no such option. Please fill a bug at spacevims issue tracker, that is clearly a bug

Comment: What SpaceVim config are you using? Does `nunmap j | nunmap k` fix the problem? If so, what SpaceVim behaviour have you lost, and do you care about that?

Comment: You can also check if there is an `autocmd` responsible for this. Check if there's anything suspicious in the output of `:autocmd CursorMoved`

Comment: I've opened an issue on github - https://github.com/SpaceVim/SpaceVim/issues/1464. Issue was resolved by SpaceVim re-installation.

Comment: This has to be the number one infuriating thing about vim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As author of SpaceVim, I can not reproduce this issue in master branch. and we do not map `j` and `k` in spacevim.

I think you should check result of `:verbose map j` or `:verbose map k`, this command will show what and where j and k is mapped.

if the result is empty, you need to check autocmd like `CursorMoved` via `:au CursorMoved`, the output will what autocmd will be called when move cursor.

Comment: thx for ur support. I've created the issue on github https://github.com/SpaceVim/SpaceVim/issues/1464. The problem has already gone  as it was problem of my installation.

Comment: nice! If you encounter other issue , you can use spacevim tag in this channel

Answer (score 1):

I am learning light vimscripting, so I am not sure if this will work. But put these in your `.vimrc`:

```
function! NextLine()
  let c = col(".")
  execute "normal! j" . c . "|"
endfunction
function! PreviousLine()
  let c = col(".")
  execute "normal! k" . c . "|"
endfunction
nnoremap j :call NextLine()
nnoremap k :call PreviousLine()
```

These will not give you native vim experience because if you go down to a line of zero column, then the next line will also be on the zeroth column, not the column of the previous column. This would require, I think, another function for checking if any <kbd>h</kbd> or l has been pressed in between the function calls to preserve intelligent column number preservation.

But I think it should get the job done for now.

Comment: The not "native vim experience" you describe seems to be exactly the behaviour the OP wants to fix?